# Nuxt 3 SSR - No console logs of server API in dev environment

Tags: server-side-rendering, vite, pnpm, nuxt3

When you do a simple console log in server API side, it doesn't show up when you build it using `pnpm run dev`.

[image: dev environment]

But if you build it using `pnpm run build` and run the `index.mjs`, the console log will show up.

Code:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  console.log('HAHAHAHAHA');

  return 'LOGIN!';
});
```

Here is my `npx nuxi info`:

```
------------------------------
- Operating System: `Linux`
- Node Version:     `v18.12.1`
- Nuxt Version:     `3.0.0`
- Nitro Version:    `1.0.0`
- Package Manager:  `pnpm@7.22.0`
- Builder:          `vite`
- User Config:      `app`, `runtimeConfig`, `modules`, `ssr`, `vite`, `typescript`, `css`, `build`
- Runtime Modules:  `@app/ui@1.0.0-alpha`, `nuxt-icon@0.1.8`, `@pinia/nuxt@0.4.6`
- Build Modules:    `-`
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Output from `console.log()` from server is output in the terminal, where you run your `pnpm run dev` command or where the server has been started.

Not on a client side. Not in a browser.